# What is this downtown side job during the Corpo prologue?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

At the start of the game for Corpo lifepath there's a side job on the map, just west of corporate plaza. It's marked "*UNDISCOVERED - Who knows what you might find?*" with "DANGER: VERY HIGH". I don't see any way to get there during the prologue. Is it possible? If it's something we're not meant to do until later, why is it showing up now?

[image: (Map Screenshot)]

Comment: You can always go to the mission location and accept the mission (or decline the mission) without actually completing any of the mission steps yet to find out what it is. It's hard to say what the mission is without trying to reproduce this exact playthrough; some missions show up only when certain conditions are met.

Comment: I've rolled a few different characters and seen this marker on every one so far. Maybe it's a bug. (Hard to imagine in this game right?) I'll come back to this once I'm far enough in the game, if nobody else knows. I've spent about 60hrs on all the side jobs and not done any main jobs yet.

Answer (score 2):

This job is **"Cyberpsycho Sighting: On Deaf Ears"**, which takes place in a mall parking garage. I could not identify it until reaching City Center. At the beginning of the game there's no way to reach that location, since the only way to leave the Arasaka office is with your boss's AV, which flies on a predetermined route.

My theory as to what causes the dot to appear so early is that it's part of the beginning tutorial on jobs. When you're in the office a popup appears explaining how the map works, and what key to press to switch between active jobs. They probably just show that extra job so players can try it out. Perhaps CDPR originally planned to have another side job within the office, but didn't have time to create that content so they just decided "unhide" a random nearby job to accomplish the same thing. Otherwise it would be a bug. Cyberpsycho sightings are among the first jobs to appear on the map after you start Act 1, but not until Regina contacts you about them.